# add-apt-repository command returns extrange error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm trying to install R 3.6.
But when I try to run the add the repository, I get a huge error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/'
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

I have no clue why this is happening.
Any help on how to adding the repository for installing R will be very welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to install an R programing language or Python ?

Comment: I am trying to install R 3.5

Comment: Are you sure ? You mean R as a separate language right ?